# How to get size of specfic value inside array Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

here is example of the list. I want to make dynamic where maybe the the value will become more.

```
val list = arrayListOf("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "B") //Maybe they will be more
```

I want the output like:-

```
val result = list[i] + " size: " + list[i].size
```

So the output will display every String with the size.

```
A size: 3
B size: 2
C size: 1
```

If I add more value, so the result will increase also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the terminology you're looking for is "frequency" here: the number of times an element appears in a list.

You can usually count elements in a list using the `count` method like this:

```kotlin
val numberOfAs = list.count { it == "A" }
```

This approach is pretty inefficient if you need to count all elements though, in which case you can create a map of frequencies the following way:

```kotlin
val freqs = list.groupBy { it }.mapValues { (_, g) -> g.size }
```

`freqs` here will be a `Map` where each key is a unique element from the original list, and the value is the corresponding frequency of that element in the list.

This works by first grouping elements that are equal to each other via `groupBy`, which returns a `Map<String, List<String>>` where each key is a unique element from the original list, and each value is the group of all elements in the list that were equal to the key.
Then `mapValues` will transform that map so that the values are the sizes of the groups instead of the groups themselves.

An improved approach, as suggested by @broot is to make use of Kotlin's `Grouping` class which has a built-in `eachCount` method:

```kotlin
val freqs = list.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()
```

Comment: `groupBy()` could be replaced with: `words.groupingBy { it }.eachCount()`. This way we avoid creating lists of values, which we don't really need here, Instead, we actually only count elements.

Comment: @broot good catch. I always forget about this one!

Comment: Thank you for good explanation! I have tried it and it is working!

Comment: @Joffrey if `freqs` with condition, example. inside "A", there are "small", and "big" . Can we divide them as count also ? Result will be = `A for small is 2`  and `A for big is 1`

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I'm sorry I don't understand your question. What do you mean by *inside "A"*? "A" is just a string, right? Or are you using "A" as a generic representation of your items but the items are in fact lists themselves?

Comment: @Joffrey yes it is. Should I create new question or update the question?

Comment: @TicherhazFreePalestine I think it might be best to open a different question, because if your items are actually lists themselves (or other kinds of compound objects), it's not the same problem I believe

Comment: @Joffrey how to remove the bracket ?

Comment: What bracket are you referring to?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `groupBy` in this way:

```
val result = list.groupBy { it }.map { it.key to it.value.size }.toMap()
```

[Jeoffrey's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67808219/9940820) way is better actually, since he is using `.mapValues()` directly, instead of an extra call to `.toMap()`. I'm just leaving this answer her since
I believe that the other info I put is relevant.

This will give a `Map<String, Int>`, where the `Int` is the count of the occurences.

This `result` will not change when you change the original `list`. That is not how the language works. If you want something like that, you'd need quite a bit of work, like overwriting the `add` function from your collection to refresh the `result` map.

Also, I see no reason for you to use an `ArrayList`, especially since you are expecting to increase the size of that collection, I'd stick with `MutableList` if I were you.

Comment: Thank you for great explanation. I have tried it and it is working. Thank you! I'm using ArrayList because need to handle with object.

Comment: I would suggest to use Joffrey's answer, especially the way broot described in the comments, it is much more efficient than mine.